# Why do Genetic Algorithms require more memory than other machine learning techniques?

Tags: genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I am currently studying genetic algorithms. There is a question that asks "Why do Genetic Algorithms require more memory than other machine learning techniques like decision trees?" I can't find any answers, even by Googling. Can anyone give and explain the answer?

Comment: Genetic algorithms run simulations, and lots of them. Unless you're creating your offspring one-by-one (not standard), you will have large populations, all in memory (unless you write to a file). Running simulations on these offspring can be very intensive, especially when you have many features you want to test with.

Comment: It's in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm). See the second bulleted paragraph under "Limitations" that starts with "Genetic algorithms do not scale well with complexity."; the sentence after that one is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Genetic Algorithms mimic the process of natural selection in order to "evolve" a solution to a difficult optimization problem. Generally, the algorithm works by first generating some random "individuals" (ie solutions to the problem you're trying to solve) and computing their "fitness" with a fitness function. More fit individuals are then selected to survive and possibly exchange "DNA" through "breeding" in order to produce the next generation of individuals. This process is then repeated until a stopping condition is reached, which might be a sufficient level of fitness achieved or a maximum number of generations reached. Fitness functions are typically very complicated functions as they must process all of an individual's "traits" and output the fitness (possibly as a scalar). For many problems, this is impossible from an algorithmic complexity standpoint, and thus fitness approximation is used instead. Either way, the iterative nature of GAs, the complexity of the fitness function, and the fact that at any given moment a large number of individuals are represented in RAM makes for a demanding algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Other techniches as simulated annealing require less resources, both, in time and memory. In the specific case of simulated annealing, you work only with an element using mutation as unique operator. For SA, memory is not a problem, normally. Calculation time is conditioned, obviously, by the nature of the problem.

GA are more flexible, but SA is a good techniche that works fine for a lot of problems using low resources.

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason that genetic algorithms require more memory is that they need to maintain an entire population of solutions. Other search methods, such as hill-climbing, tabu search, beam search, and simulated annealing just deal with one solution at a time. So if, for instance, a solution requires a megabyte of RAM to represent, a GA with a population size of 100 will require 100 megabytes of RAM to represent its population of solutions.

As Treker mentioned, the fact that you also often need to evaluate all of the solutions in the population can add an additional memory cost.